problems with custom authentication provider in spring boot 3.3.0
I've been struggling with this for too many days and could really use some help.  I am trying to use spring-boot 3.3.0 to create an unusual authentication provider.  I need it to work like this:

app will be loaded into the iframe of another website we will call the "referer"
app is loaded with a GET request containing params for id, name, and email
the initial request could be for any item
the auth provider should validate the first request where the "Referer" request header starts with a specific value and the "Sec-Fetch-Dest" contains "iframe"
upon validation the user should be granted a role authority and a session for subsequent requests
the id, name, and email should be available within the Authentication for use within services and thymeleaf

public class RefererAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

  private static final AntPathRequestMatcher DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER = new AntPathRequestMatcher("**","GET");

  public RefererAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    super(DEFAULT_ANT_PATH_REQUEST_MATCHER, authenticationManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String url        = request.getHeader( "Referer" );
    String fetchDest  = request.getHeader( "Sec-Fetch-Dest" );
    String id         = request.getParameter( "id" );
    String name       = request.getParameter( "name" );
    String email      = request.getParameter( "email" );
    String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
    if (ipAddress == null) {
      ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }

    Referer referer = new Referer();
    referer.setUrl(url);
    referer.setFetchDest(fetchDest);
    referer.setId(id);
    referer.setName(name);
    referer.setEmail(email);
    referer.setIpAddress(ipAddress);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( referer, null );
    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
  }
}

@Component
public class RefererAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Value("${referer}")
  private String validReferer;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken challengeAuth = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    log.debug( "starting authentication ..." );
    Referer referer = (Referer) challengeAuth.getPrincipal();
    if ( referer.getUrl().startsWith(validReferer) &&
         referer.getFetchDest().equals("iframe") ) {
      SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
      List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
      grantedAuthorities.add(authority);
      return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( referer, null, grantedAuthorities);
    }
    throw new BadCredentialsException("referer did not match within the iframe");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals( UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class );
  }

}

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

  @Autowired
  RefererAuthenticationProvider refererAuthenticationProvider;

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(refererAuthenticationProvider);
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
    RefererAuthenticationFilter refererAuthenticationFilter = new RefererAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager);
    refererAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    return http
      .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
      .addFilterAt(refererAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .authorizeHttpRequests( request -> { request
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
      })
      .headers( headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable) )
      .build();
  }

}

This ends up just telling me ...
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)"
because the return value of "com.example.security.filter.RefererAuthenticationFilter.getAuthenticationManager()" is null

I thought I could use the default AuthenticationManager.
To make the situation even more challenging I want multiple AuthenticationProviders.  I want this one to be tried first, followed by okta-spring-boot-starter 3.0.6. I'm not sure if these can co-exist in the same AuthenticationManager, who provides it, and where exactly I would try to lay down my RefererAuthenticationFilter in the filter chain with Okta, which looks like
org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4bf806ab, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2e7b49c0, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1e26110d, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1e1b3778, 
org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5dd7342f, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1865d91, 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@5d116afe, 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@1780aa5d, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@264c6be6, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@3f60f8c4, 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4650f833, 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3acc81dd, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@34a66cdd, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@206f53b0, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@fbb75c2

